# Ionic2 @angular dependency in package.json

Tags: ionic2

While creating a new project using "ionic start #appName# blank --v2 --ts" command.
So it shows

```
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/common": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
  "@angular/compiler": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
  "@angular/core": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
  "@angular/http": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
  "@angular/router": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
```

in package.json.

What is the command to create a new project using old version of ionic2 so that is get "angular2" instead of "@angular" and can use old RouteConfig

Answer (score 0):

I used this configuration for ionic2 beta 5 version.

```
 "dependencies": {
"angular2": "2.0.0-beta.15",
"es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
"ionic-angular": "2.0.0-beta.5-201604211454",
"ionic-native": "^1.1.0",
"ionicons": "3.0.0-alpha.3",
"reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
"zone.js": "^0.6.11"
```

},

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "del": "2.2.0",
    "gulp": "3.9.1",
    "gulp-watch": "4.3.5",
    "ionic-gulp-browserify-es2015": "^1.0.2",
    "ionic-gulp-fonts-copy": "^1.0.0",
    "ionic-gulp-html-copy": "^1.0.0",
    "ionic-gulp-sass-build": "^1.0.0",
    "ionic-gulp-scripts-copy": "^1.0.0",
    "run-sequence": "1.1.5"
  }
```

you have to delete all from node_modules folder, change package.config file with config from above and run npm install 
But you have to take in consideration that this is an old version of ionic (beta5) and angular. My suggestion is to use the latest versions